# can't get autocomplete text

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I try to get the string I wrote in the autocomplete to use it later

```
AutoCompleteTextView from_txt;
List<String> country_List;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

then

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   AutoCompleteTextView from_txt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from_txt);
    from_txt.setThreshold(1);
 from_txt.addTextChangedListener( this);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
 (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,country_List);
    from_txt.setAdapter(adapter);
    handler = new Handler();
```

then I try to get the text

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), from_txt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

}
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" means? Does it crash? It shows nothing?

Comment: Does the `AutoCompleteTextView R.id.from_txt` exists in your `R.layout.main` layout?

Comment: if crashes..then crash report i.e logcat will help to understand ..will you provide it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AutoCompleteTextView` object is being defining twice. Just replace:

```
AutoCompleteTextView from_txt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from_txt);
```

with:

```
from_txt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.from_txt);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I made such mistake :)